# Adding tags to ec2-Snapshots via powershell

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, aws-powershell

I am trying to add tags to snapshots within AWS EC2 environment using powershell so that i can tag them for use down the road and some graduated snapshot retention.

I can manually create them through the console but for the life of me cannot find out which cmdlet to use.  The best I've able to manage is edit-ec2snapshotattribute but that does not appear to be what I want.
I would rather not use the 'description' if possible during the creation of the snapshot as that is being used for other items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cmdlet New-EC2Tag can be used to create new tags for any EC2 resource, including snapshots.

Example:

```
# Create a new tag with Key "Environment" and Value "Dev"
PS C:\> New-EC2Tag -Resources "snap-1a2b3c4d" -Tags @{ Key="Environment"; Value = "Dev" }

# View the newly created tag on the snapshot
PS C:\> Get-EC2Snapshot -SnapshotIds "snap-1a2b3c4d" | % { $_.Tags }

Key                                                         Value
---                                                         -----
Environment                                                 Dev
```

Documentation:

- [AWS Tools For PowerShell - New-EC2Tag](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/New-EC2Tag.html)
- [AWS Tools For PowerShell - Get-EC2Snapshot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-EC2Snapshot.html)
- [AWS User Guide - Tagging Your EC2 Resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html) (includes a list of all EC2 resource types that can be tagged)